# No starting animation on Bootstrap Collapse animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Bootstraps Collapse to my menu. On the mobile whenever the user clicks on the burger menu, the menu appears without a transition. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? (Bare in mind this is from my Wordpress theme so the code won't work here) To see the code on the website, go to test.derektierney.co.uk

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <title><? bloginfo('name'); ?> | 
    <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background: #122f58; padding: 20px 10%;" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://test.derektierney.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Think-Mad-Company-Logo-White.svg" style="width: 150px;"></img></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),) 
            );
        ?>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I see that the target is specified to two elements in the HTML: https://nimb.ws/0MXGNz It could be a problem. Think about it, if two transitions are working on nested elements, how would it behave.

Comment: @m4n0 Thank you so much, I dont know how I never seen this.